# Android Boot receiver doesn't fire

Tags: android

I have a boot receiver set up in my manifest which launches a WakefulBroadcastReceiver which then starts a ServiceIntent to create alarms.

My manifest has this:

```
<receiver android:name=".controllers.receivers.AlarmBootReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

As well as the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

My AlarmBootReceiver is this:

```
public class AlarmBootReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent alarmBootServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmBootService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, alarmBootServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

and my IntentService is this:

```
public class AlarmBootService extends IntentService {
    public AlarmBootService() {
        super("AlarmBootService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.wtf("Boot", "Boot receiver started");
        //Get list of classes from realm and set up alarms for each
        Realm.init(getBaseContext());
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        RealmResults<Class> classes = realm.where(Class.class).findAll();
        //For each day in days string, create an alarm an hour before fromtime
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
        for (Class c : classes) {
            for (char day : c.getDays().toCharArray()) {
                //Convert SMTWRFA char to calendar day int
                int d = ClassDialog.charToDay(day);
                //Create the alarm
                ma.createWeeklyAlarmForDay(d, c.getName(),
                c.getBuilding(),
                c.getFromAMPM().equals("AM") ? Calendar.AM : Calendar.PM,
                c.getTimeFromH(), c.getTimeFromM());
            }
        }
        //Release wakelock
        AlarmBootReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

But the service never appears to be launched. I never see my "Boot receiver started" log in the output, and alarms aren't registered. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Is it getting into onReceive() in AlarmBootReceiver?  Also, has the app launched an Activity at least once?

Comment: Looks like no, and yes it was opened

Comment: Looks like it should be working.  Is the `.controllers.receivers.AlarmBootReceiver` package correct?  What's the full package for AlarmBootReceiver?

Comment: changed it to include the full package and it worked! it's a little delayed but it works now. Weird

Comment: submit an answer and i'll accept it

Comment: I also needed to declare the IntentService in the manifest, as well as add the wake_lock permission.